# Positivity of an operator on a compact subset of a manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, operator-theory, differential-operators, pseudo-differential-operators

Let $E$ and $F$ be two vector bundles over manifold $X$. Let $P:\Gamma(E)\to \Gamma(F)$ be a self-adjoint differential operator over $X$. Define inner product on the spaces $\Gamma(E)$ of smooth sections over $X$ by the following pointwise inner product:

$$(s_1,s_2):=\int_X <s_1(x),s_2(x)>,\quad s_1,s_2\in\Gamma(E)$$

My question is how to prove that there exists a constant $k>0$ such that

$$P+k\ Id\geq 0$$  holds on a compact subset $K\subset X$. That is,

$$((P+k\ Id) s,s)\geq 0, \quad s\in\Gamma(E).$$ holds on a compact subset $K\subset X$.

I'm a little confused to prove the inequality. Could you please give me some help with the details? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think there’s any completely general method for doing so. In the case of the generalised Dirac operator $D$ induced by a Clifford connection $\nabla$ on a Clifford module bundle $E$ on a complete Riemannian manifold $X$ (e.g., the spin Dirac operator on a complete Riemannian spin manifold), you have a Lichnerowicz formula $$D^2 = \nabla^\ast \nabla + \frac{1}{4}\operatorname{Sc} \operatorname{Id} + \mathcal{F}^{E/S},$$ where $\operatorname{Sc}$ is the scalar curvature of $X$ and $\mathcal{F}^{E/S}$ is a pointwise symmetric smooth bundle endomorphism of $E$ encoding the so-called twisting curvature of the Clifford module bundle $\mathcal{E}$ (e.g., $\mathcal{F}^{E/S} = 0$ when $D$ is a spin Dirac operator). Then
$$
 \forall \sigma \in \Gamma_c(E), \quad (D^2s,s) = \lVert \nabla s \rVert^2_2 +\left((\tfrac{1}{4}\operatorname{Sc}\operatorname{Id}+\mathcal{F}^{E/S})s,s\right) \geq \left((\tfrac{1}{4}\operatorname{Sc}\operatorname{Id}+\mathcal{F}^{E/S})s,s\right).
$$
But now, since $\tfrac{1}{4}\operatorname{Sc}\operatorname{Id}+\mathcal{F}^{E/S}$ is a smooth (hence continuous) bundle endomorphism, the usual extreme value theorem together with a tiny bit of care imply that for *every* compact $K \subset X$, there exists $\kappa_1[K] > 0$, such that $-\left(\tfrac{1}{4}\operatorname{Sc}\operatorname{Id}+\mathcal{F}^{E/S}\right) \leq \kappa_1[K]\operatorname{Id}$ pointwise on $K$, in which case
$$
 \forall \sigma \in \Gamma(E), \quad ((D^2+\kappa_1[K]\operatorname{id})s,s)_K \geq \left((\tfrac{1}{4}\operatorname{Sc}\operatorname{Id}+\mathcal{F}^{E/S})s,s\right)_K + \left(\kappa_1[K]\operatorname{id}s,s\right)_K \geq 0.
$$

The existence of $\kappa_1[K]$ now follows from the following straightforward lemma:

> Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a pointwise symmetric smooth bundle endomorphism of a Hermitian vector bundle $E$ on a smooth manifold $X$. For every compact $K \subset X$, there exists constant $C[K] > 0$, such that $\mathcal{F} \leq C[K]\operatorname{id}$ pointwise on $K$, i.e.,
> $$
>  \forall x \in K, \, \forall \sigma_x \in E_x, \quad \langle\mathcal{F}\sigma_x,\sigma_x\rangle_x \leq C[K]\langle \sigma_x,\sigma_x \rangle_x.
> $$

**Proof.** Since $X$ is locally Euclidean and $E$ is locally trivial, without loss of generality, $X = \mathbb{R}^n$ and $E$ is trivial with fibre $\mathbb{C}^r$. By applying Gram–Schmidt to the standard ordered basis of $\mathbb{C}^r$, we therefore obtain an orthonormal frame $(e_1,\dotsc,e_r)$ for $E$ consisting of smooth global sections. Thus, since $K$ is compact, let
$$
 C[K] := 1+r^2 \max_{1\leq i,j \leq r} \max_{x \in K} \lvert \langle \mathcal{F}_x (e_i)_x,(e_j)_x \rangle _x \rvert.
$$
Then, for all $x \in X$ and $\sigma_x \in E_x$,
$$\begin{align}
\langle \mathcal{F}_x \sigma_x,\sigma_x \rangle_x &= \sum_{i,j=1}^r \langle \mathcal{F}_x (e_i)_x,(e_j)_x\rangle_x \langle \sigma_x, (e_i)_x \rangle_x \overline{\langle \sigma_x, (e_j)_x \rangle_x}\\
&\leq \sum_{i,j=1}^r \lvert\langle \mathcal{F}_x (e_i)_x,(e_j)_x\rangle_x \rvert \cdot \lvert\langle \sigma_x, (e_i)_x \rangle_x \rvert \cdot \lvert \overline{\langle \sigma_x, (e_j)_x \rangle_x}\rvert\\
&\leq \sum_{i,j=1}^r \lvert\langle \mathcal{F}_x (e_i)_x,(e_j)_x\rangle_x \rvert \cdot \sqrt{\langle \sigma_x,\sigma_x \rangle_x} \cdot \sqrt{\langle \sigma_x,\sigma_x \rangle_x}\\
&\leq \sum_{i,j=1}^r \left(\max_{y \in K} \lvert\langle \mathcal{F}_y (e_i)_y,(e_j)_y\rangle_x \rvert\right) \langle \sigma_x,\sigma_x \rangle_x\\
&\leq C[K] \langle \sigma_x,\sigma_x \rangle_x. 
\end{align}$$
There are obviously slicker ways to get sharper estimates, but this is good enough for this particular purpose.

Comment: A detailed proof is right there. It’s standard folklore.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, do you know about the definition and existence of parametrices or Green operators associated with a generalized Dirac operators on complete noncompact manifolds? Is there some differences contrasting with compact case? I'm confused with this question for a long time, and I can't find some reference about it. Could you please give me some help? Thanks again!

Comment: Here is the link of my question : https://mathoverflow.net/q/407049/130954 @BranimirĆaćić

Comment: In all honesty, I don’t think you’ll get much more accessible an account than Section 1 of Gromov–Lawson. To the best of my knowledge, the most detailed accounts of Dirac operators focus on the compact case because they have the usual Atiyah–Singer index theorem in mind. You might want to look at the relevant chapters of Higson–Roe or Willett–Yu, but neither goes into the kind of detail you want.

Comment: I just want to understand their paper in 1983, but it seems that they haven't give more explanation for Green operators and parametrices in complete noncompact case. Could you help me with some difficulties in the proof of a theorem in the link I gave just now? I don't understand why it suffice to prove the space $H_c$ is finite dimensional. Thanks

Comment: In the proof of above lemma you used, why does the first equality hold? Couly you please explain it? Thanks

Comment: That’s literally just using the fact that $((e_1)_x,\dotsc,(e_r)_x)$ is an orthonormal basis for $E_x$.